# loading image inside textbox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, textbox

Ive noticed, on a few sites, that some text boxes have spinning 'loading' images in them when a person finishes entering data.

Eg: On a registration page, when a user enters a nickname. When they are dont, the system checks the DB to see if it is unique.

In this time, the text box displays a spinning loader INSIDE of it, and then a tick or cross image (replacing the loader) if the name is valid or not.

How would I go about implementing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to strip out all the default style of a textbox and rebuild it yourself with background images and other styles.  In addition, you would need to implement AJAX to handle any checks against a database.  Not something easy to answer in this format, but I would suggest using FireBug to explore the site you like and see what they have done.

EDIT:

This isn't *exactly* what you are looking for, but this might help.  I added a bunch of custom styling to a textbox and other than a little JS to show/hide the AJAX spinner, hopefully this will get you part of the way there.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="search_box">
    <input id="txt_search" type="text" />
    <img src="/images/btn_submit.png" alt="Submit" id="btn_search" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search_box {background:url(/images/txt_main.png) 0 0 no-repeat;height:40px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;width:386px;}
#search_box input 
{
    background:none;
    border:0;
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:2px 0 0 1px;
    outline:none;
    padding:6px;
    width:330px;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
}
#search_box img {float:right;margin:5px 6px 0 0;}
```

EDIT:

Attaching image.

[image]

Comment: I have the code behind working all well, including the ajax. All I need to do in implement the image-inside idea. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I had a thought that lead to almost exactly what you did, but it stopped at just a thought! Thank you for your input, I will do something along your lines, and update my question with the results :)

Comment: May I ask what your div image is, or where I could get it? - I ask because I cant get the border-radius working properly on a div (the border disappears on the radial corner)..

Comment: Just updated the post to include the image.  Its a rounded corner PNG - I don't do any rounding with CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the image :D Is there a reason why you dont round corners with CSS?

Comment: When I was working on this project, IE7 was still a consideration and doesn't support border-radius.  Plus I wanted to add a little more style with the background image.

Comment: Haha agreed! Thanks for the solution, and I will be marking it as such - though other people /should/ take a look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Spinning.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Spinning" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#namebox").blur(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                    $("#namebox").addClass("spinnerLoader");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Spinning.aspx/CheckName",
                        data: "{name:'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $("#namebox").removeClass("spinnerLoader");
                            if (msg.d == "ok") {
                                $("#namebox").addClass("ok");
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#namebox").addClass("error");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#namebox").removeClass("spinnerLoader");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .spinner
        {
            background-position: right;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        .spinnerLoader
        {
            background-image: url(spinner.gif);
        }
        .ok
        {
            background-image: url(accept.png);
        }
        .error
        {
            background-image:url(error.png);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="spinner" id="namebox" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript handles the event when the text box loses focus and then calls a page method in the page using ajax, the code behind looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Spinning : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static string CheckName(string name)
        {
            if (name.Equals("test"))
                return "ok";

            return "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

which will check the entered value and return ok if it is test and fail otherwise. Hope this can help.

Comment: May be insulting to say, but I have no idea how to tie that into postbacks, databinding, or code behind!

Comment: I get the feeling that a postback method isnt theere... This does.. Nothing :P

Comment: There is a POST to the WebMethod in the page, where you can do for example a check against a DB, but there is no regular PostBack, which I guessed you didn't want since you are using ajax?

Comment: Ajax catches the regular postback and turns it into a half-postback.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on @TrueDevelopment's answer**

```
<div id="Div1" class="styleDivLoader">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtWebsite" runat="server" CssClass="styleTextBoxNone" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtWebsite_TextChanged" />
     <asp:Image ID="imgWebsiteLoader" runat="server" CssClass="styleImageTextBox" Visible="False" />
     <asp:Label ID="lblWebsiteTitle" runat="server" CssClass="styleLabelWatermark"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Then

```
.styleDivLoader {
    background: white;
    padding: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    width: 446px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.styleTextBoxNone {
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid darkgrey;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 260px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px;
    -webkit-appearance:none;

}

.styleImageTextBox {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```